# Python use alias for inner classes

Tags: python

I have following code sample,

```
class Outer:
    class InnerException(Exception): pass
    def raise_inner(self):
        raise Outer.InnerException()
    def call_raise(self):
        try:
            self.raise_inner()
        except Outer.InnerException as e:
            print "Handle me"

 Outer().call_raise()
```

What I wish to do is instead of using `Outer.InnerException` just use `InnerException` inside the Outer class, in short something like this

```
class Outer:
    class InnerException(Exception): pass

    #InnerException = Outer.InnerException .. something like this, create some alias

    def raise_inner(self):
        raise InnerException()
    def call_raise(self):
        try:
            self.raise_inner()
        except InnerException as e:
            print "Handle me"

 Outer().call_raise()
```

Comment: Usual approach in Python:  Put the exception class at module scope.

Comment: See this answer regarding Python's [LEGB Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/355230).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just refer to things declared in class scope with a name (unless you are doing so also in class scope).

Either do:

```
class Outer:
    class InnerException(Exception): pass
    def raise_inner(self):
        raise self.InnerException()
```

or

```
class InnerException(Exception): pass
class Outer:
    def raise_inner(self):
        raise InnerException()
```

Answer (score 1):

The name `InnerException` is looked up at the time the method is called, so the exception name is a non-local value. You could write

```
class Outer:
    class InnerException(Exception): pass

    # methods

InnerException = Outer.InnerException
```

but that mostly defeats the purpose of defining `InnerException` inside the class `Outer` in the first place. You could just as easily write

```
class Outer:
    # methods

class InnerException(Exception): pass
```

because both make the name `InnerException` refer to an exception in the module scope (although in the second case, `InnerException` is no longer a class attribute of `Outer`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do something like this to define it within each function's enclosing scope, which creates a local variable that's an alias for it:

```
class Outer:
    class InnerException(Exception): pass
    def raise_inner(self, InnerException=InnerException):
        raise InnerException()
    def call_raise(self, InnerException=InnerException):
        try:
            self.raise_inner()
        except InnerException as e:
            print "Handle me"

Outer().call_raise()
```